# Error with Gitlab: Sidekiq; gemfile syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rvm, gitlab

I've been breaking my head over this error for hours now, and still haven't found a fix. When I run sidekiq using `sudo -u root -H RAILS_ENV=production script/background_jobs start` I'm getting this error in the sidekiq.log:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
/home/website/git/gitlab/Gemfile:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem "mysql2", group: :mysql
```

I've installed Ruby 2.1.0 and am running CentOS. I've seen other posts with this error, and their problem was that they were running Ruby 1.8, however, I'm running Ruby 2.1.0 and also getting this error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My gemfile http://pastebin.com/T5z4GZ3a

`bundle` returns

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development, test, postgres, puma and aws were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

EDIT2: My `background_jobs` script http://pastebin.com/kdicTFqk

`bundle show bundler` returns

```
2.1.0
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2
```

EDIT3: I think I have found the problem, not sure how to solve it though. I added `p RUBY_VERSION` as first line of my Gemfile, then I changed every line written like this: `group: :mysql` to this `:group => :mysql` (because that is working on older versions).

However, when I run Sidekiq now, this shows up in the sidekiq.log:

```
"1.8.7"
bundler: command not found: sidekiq
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I am really, really confused now. Here it clearly says my Ruby version is 1.8.7, but that's not right. `ruby -v` or `rvm list rubies` only show that Ruby 2.1.0 is installed, and set as default.

Comment: Please post your whole Gemfile. Also put a `puts RUBY_VERSION` at the beginning of your Gemfile to verify that you're using the correct version and do a `bundle`.

Comment: @Agis Updated post. If I add `puts RUBY_VERSION` at the beginning, when I run `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` it outputs the version number 2.1.0 at the begin.

Comment: show also output of the `bundle show bundler`, and try to replace that line with `gem "mysql2", group => :mysql`

Comment: Seems like the `background_jobs` picks up Ruby 1.8 for some reason. Can you paste us this script? @majioa you mean `gem "mysql2", :group => :mysql`.

Comment: @Agis Added link to script, see edit2.

Comment: @Agis Updated the main post, please read edit 3 if you can.

Comment: it shows that `sidekiq` script ignores the ruby 2.1 installation from rvm env and try to use systems ruby. How do you run the script? And what is the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that when you issue `bundle install` you have picked up the *ruby 2.1.0*, just do as follows:

1. Enter into app's folder, then edit the **Gemfile** to a few lines, inserting into it `p RUBY_VERSION`
2. Issue `bundle install`, and see the ruby version output, it shell be 2.1.0, and the form of `gem "mysql2", group: :mysql` should work.

   ```
   2.1.0
   ```
3. Then add line one-by-one, or group-by-group, issuing the `bundle install`
4. So make sure that the **Gemfile** will be fully restored at the end.
5. Then you should do a proper setup shell environment in your run script. So if you use the *rvm* just replace the first line with:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -l
   ```
6. Add sourcing to rvm:

   ```
   source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   ```
7. Before starting the script, add shell command to set proper version of *ruby* to *2.1.0*

   ```
   rvm use ruby-2.1.0@global
   ```

**NOTE:** Probably you have to use an other *gemset* not the *`global`* one.

Comment: Did step 1 and 2, and it indeed says "2.1.0" after I do `bundle install`. What am I supposed to do at step 3?

Comment: @Martijnie what says the `bundle exec ruby -v`